# search in 2 tables if field has value every hour

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 tables one name unete_info and unete_confirmation. unete info has all basic information for a registry and unete confirmation has a field name joind_id which is generated when user successfully registered.

join_id is located in both tables as well name last_name and email, email is the unique value to validate both tables. i need to check whithin the tables every hour to see if the user the register successfully if not get a notificacion i have a user pending.

meaning my query needs to check within both tables and if user has join id empty in both tables after an hour send a notfication. but so far i need first how to get the user that dont have join_id, so far i came up with this.

```
SELECT  unete_info.name,unete_info.last_name,unete_info.age,unete_info.number,unete_info.language,unete_info.submitted,unete_confirmation.join_id
FROM unete_info
INNER JOIN unete_confirmation ON unete_info.email=unete_confirmation.email
```

im missing how to check every hour and how to get users that join_id is null(empty)

Comment: You need a Cron job for checking hourly

Comment: ok i create a job to execute every hour, but how do i get the users that doesnt have join_id values on both tables

Comment: You need to have a Cron job to run every hour. That Cron job will run a script, Im guessing PHP, and that script will do the logic for you and interact with whatever it is you need it to interact with.

Comment: i got you, but the script is what i need basically